# mongoose - trying to save an array of documents, only empty array saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema defined like this

```
var PersonelModelSchema = new Schema({
  emailAddress: String,
  fullName: String
});

var ModuleModelSchema = new Schema({
  modName: String,
  personels:[PersonelModelSchema ]
});


var ModulesModelSchema=new Schema({
  modules: [ModuleModelSchema ]
});

var ModulesModel = mongoose.model('ModulesModel ', ModulesModelSchema );
```

This schema is used to save data sent by another app to an api end point built on nodejs

The json data contains an array, the contents of which I want to save as separate documents - ie is the array has 2 objects, each needs to be saved as separate documents. This is the reason I am using array if ModuleModelSchema, so that I can get all the objects in array.

The data that is posted is looks like this

```
{"modfulldata" :[{
  "modName": "example-45435q5",
  personels: [
    {
      "emailAddress": "name@example",
      "fullName": "name"
    },
    {
      "emailAddress": "name2@example",
      "fullName": "name2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "modName": "example-f45b",
  personels: [
    {
      "emailAddress": "name3@example",
      "fullName": "name3"
    },
    {
      "emailAddress": "name4@example",
      "fullName": "name4"
    }
  
  ]
}
]}
```

And this is the code I am using to save

```
app.post('/savemd', 
    function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body.modfulldata);// the data is shown correctly here

        mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true });
        var db = mongoose.connection;
        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.once('open', function callback () {
            console.log("open");          

        });

        var newmods=new ModulesModel (req.body.modfulldata);
        
    ModulesModel.insertMany(newmods).then(function(){
                db.close();
        });

    });
```

There are no errors thrown. With the console.log statement, i can see the request json data is read correctly.
However in mongodb, there is only an empty array in the saved document

[image: mongodb result]

What am I doing wrong?

How to save the data correctly?

Comment: probably, it's somehow relevand with the `_id` field (and it's generation) for embed docs inside the array. Mongoose won't return you an error, because the doc is saved successfully. Also, you may find useful this answer about ar of mine, if you will try to work and [update the array field via `.save()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701711/saving-an-array-in-mongoose-save/66703393#66703393) in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the `body.modfulldata` is an array and you simply can not create mongoose schema object like this, instead iterate the array and generate mongoose schema object and then insert them. Example:

```js
const newmods = req.body.modfulldata.map(dataObj => {
                  return new ModulesModel(dataObj);
                });
await ModuleModel.insertMany(newmods);
```

Comment: I get an error  ModuleModel.insert is not a function

Comment: never mind, works now. used "insertMany" instead of "insert". any specific reason for using "insert" in your answer?

Comment: Hey maX, pardon, this was a mistake, and fixing the same.