# Saving an array in Mongoose save

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Need help with arrays in Mongoose. Here is how my schema looks :-

```
const alertsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Alert_Date: String,
  Alert_StartTime: String,
  Alert_EndTime: String,
  Alert_RuleName: String,
  Alert_RuleId: String,
  Alert_EntryNumber: String,
  Alert_AlertId: String,
  Alert_Description: String,
  Alert_TriggerTime: String,
  Alert_Activities: [{
    Alert_Activities_ActivityType: String,
    Alert_Activities_ActivityTime: String,
    Alert_Activities_AreaName: String,
    Alert_Activities_AreaType: String,
    Alert_Activities_Position: Array,
    Alert_Activities_Duration: Number,
    Alert_Activities_SecondVesselId: String,
    Alert_Activities_SecondVesselName: String,
    Alert_Activities_SecondVesselClassCalc: String,
    Alert_Activities_SecondVesselSize: String,
    Alert_Activities_SecondVesselMMSI: String,
    Alert_Activities_SecondVesselIMO: String,
  }],
})
```

The Alert_Activities is an array coming from my upstream node js application. I implemented a fswatch functionality and as soon as a particular file changes, I am looking to save the record in my collection. The upstream file will always contain an array. Generally on an average of around 4 to 5 records. In short Alert_Activities will be there for every element of the array.

I am running a for loop and then trying to save all four elements in one go into my collection.myObject is the full array read from the upstream file using fs.read

```
for(i=0; i<myObject.length; i++){
          var newAlertData = new alertRegister({
            Alert_Date: date1,
            Alert_StartTime: startNotificationDate,
            Alert_EndTime: endNotificationDate,
            Alert_RuleName: myObject[i].ruleName,
            Alert_RuleId: myObject[i].ruleId,
            Alert_EntryNumber: myObject[i].entryNumber,
            Alert_AlertId: myObject[i].alertId,
            Alert_Description: myObject[i].description,
            Alert_TriggerTime: myObject[i].triggerTime,
            // Alert_Activities: myObject[i].activities,
          });
          newAlertData.save(function(err,data1){
            if(err){
              console.log(err)
            } else {
              console.log("data saved")
            }
          })
```

The Alert_Activities will obviously not save. What is the right way to do this in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with Mongoose Documents, not with `.lean()` javascript objects, probably, you'll need to mark array field(s) as modified via [`markModified`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-markModified) and only then use `.save()`.

> *Also, [`directModifiedPaths`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-directModifiedPaths) could help you to check, what fields has been modified in the document.*

I have noticed that your `Alert_Activities`, is actually an array of objects, so make sure that the result mongoose documents, which you are trying to `.save()` really satisfy all the validation rules.

If changes on some fields do successfully saved but the others - don't, then if's definitely something wrong with field names, or validation. And the DB/mongoose doesn't trigger you an error, because the document has already been saved, even in particular.